# Opencart Query the database to get price and attributes of products

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, opencart

Opencart Query the database to get price and attributes of products having same UPC Code. For example you are publishing products from several stores like amazon and ebay in your opencart and want to compare a product for price based on upc.

Therefore, I need to display products having same UPC code.

Can someone create a simple database query for me that I can put on product.tpl page on opencart to show the products price and attributes. The query will take the upc from product detail page's upc code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to extract products from table "products" with same upc code:

```
SELECT * FROM products AS pr
 JOIN products AS pr2 ON pr.upc_code = pr2.upc_code AND pr.id <> pr2.id
```